# Access Members of ObjectA from contained ObjectB

Tags: c#, class, design-patterns, tree

If I have several levels of object containment in an object tree where:

`ObjectA` contains a `List<ClassB> ObjectBs`
=> `ObjectB` contains a `List<ClassC> ObjectCs`
===> And so on...

Is there an easy way/design pattern to access a variable/member of ObjectA through its containing member Object C?

For example:

```
nameOfObjectA = ObjectC.GetUpmostContainer().GetName()
```

Curently I am instantiating the tree recursevily and with my knowledge I would need to pass the name of `ObjectA` on each instantiation of an object, which will be contained by `ObjectA`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a "Parent" to each Object and enforce setting the parent in the constructor of the sub-Object.

Ideally the parent-type is an interface which all of your Objects/Classes implement.

So basically it would be like:

```
interface MyNodeBase
{
    public MyNode Parent {get;}
    public string Name {get;}
}

class MyNode1 : MyNodeBase
{
    public MyNode1(MyNodeBase parent)
    {
    }
...
}
```

With that you have the possibility to navigate up until the point your are interested. You can add any helpful properties/methods to the interface.

cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about this idea but as soon as I get a tree were Object A has a List of ObjectBs and one ObjectB has a list of ObjectAs this solution is not that clean anymore, since ObjectA now has to implement that interface aswell, although some ObjectAs will never have a parent.

Comment: Hi, at the top you said you have a tree-like structure. In your comment you describe a graph-like structure - so the solution depends heavily on the nature of your structure.

Comment: ObjectA would have to implement the interface too - setting the parent to "null" would indicate a root-node